# How to specify the directory where to save the best checkpoint directories?

Tags: ray

ray.air.session.report(https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/api_docs/trainable.html?highlight=air.CheckpointConfig#class-api-checkpointing) mentions that it moves checkpoints to a new path. Is there a way to specify what path is (default is /tmp/)?